# vector::push_back: Access violation writing location

Tags: c++

Добавил в проект новый класс, который частично повторяет функционал уже существующего. В существовавшем до этого классе никаких проблем с приведенной ниже конструкцией не было.

**Что должно происходить:** создается объект пользовательского типа (если точнее, то `shared_ptr` на него) и он добавляется в вектор, хранящий эти объекты, который объявлен в свойствах нового класса.

**Что происходит на самом деле:** `First-chance exception at 0x00E791BD in MGCPserver.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x64CA0002.` При вызове `RoomsVec_.push_back`.

**Описание класса:**

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Room.h"
class Control
{
public:
    SHP_Room CreateNewRoom();
private:
    std::vector<SHP_Room> RoomsVec_; // вектор существующих комнат
};

SHP_Room Control::CreateNewRoom()
{
    /*Создаем комнату*/
    SHP_Room NewRoom(new Room());
    RoomsVec_.push_back(NewRoom);
    return NewRoom;
}
```

Причем точно такая же функция и вектор с таким же названием и типом есть в методах и свойствах другого класса.

В чем может быть дело?

Дебагер указывает на сточку в реализации функции типа `vector` - `push_back(...)`:

```
void push_back(const value_type& _Val)
{    // insert element at end
    if (_Inside(_STD addressof(_Val))) {    // push back an element
        size_type _Idx = _STD addressof(_Val) - this->_Myfirst;
        if (this->_Mylast == this->_Myend)
        _Reserve(1);
        _Orphan_range(this->_Mylast, this->_Mylast);
        this->_Getal().construct(this->_Mylast,
                this->_Myfirst[_Idx]);
        ++this->_Mylast;
    } else {    // push back a non-element
        if (this->_Mylast == this->_Myend)
        _Reserve(1);
        _Orphan_range(this->_Mylast, this->_Mylast);
        this->_Getal().construct(this->_Mylast,
                _Val); // вот сюда указывает
        ++this->_Mylast;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** Описание класса, к котором создается объект класса `Control` и само создание:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Control.h"
#include "Room.h"

class Control;

class Server
{
public:
    Control* Controller;
    Server(const TArgs&)
    {
        Control ff;
        Controller = &ff;
    }
private:
    std::vector<SHP_Room> RoomsVec_; 
    SHP_Room CreateNewRoom();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь:

```
Server(const TArgs&)
{
    Control ff;
    Controller = &ff;
}
```

Вы создаете объект типа `Control` с автоматической продолжительностью хранения - это значит, что при выходе из конструктора объект будет удален, соответственно указатель `Controller` будет ссылаться на удаленный участок памяти. Поэтому и возникает ошибка.

Возможный вариант решения проблемы:

```
std::unique_ptr<Control> Controller;
Server(const TArgs&)  : Controller(new Control) {
   /*NOP*/
}
```

Comment: Ясно, а как сделать так, чтобы он был с постоянной продолжительностью хранения?

Comment: @Dmitry выделять память оператором `new`.

Comment: @Dmitry, добавил вариант решения проблемы.